# How do we perform a natural join operation on two tables belonging to two different databases of the same DBMS?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, schema

How do we perform a natural join operation on two tables belonging to two different databases of the same DBMS?

Suppose the relation r belongs to the schema R while the relation s belongs to schema S in the same DBMS software of my PC, then why does the following SQL query doesn't work:

```
SELECT name FROM r JOIN s ON r.name = s.name
```

Comment: What error are you getting?  Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: ErrorCode: 1146 Table s.name doesn't exists

Comment: What DBMS do you use? And are the tables in different schemas or different databases? You use both words in your question but in most DBMS they aren't synonym.

Comment: `s.name` is not a table.  It is a column reference.  I cannot see how your query would generate that problem.

Comment: It is a part of the condition where the 'column values'  s.name and r.name are same in the two tables r and s.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server then

```
SELECT name FROM R.dbo.r JOIN S.dbo.s ON r.name = s.name
```

If your database is MySQL then please try this:

```
SELECT name FROM R.r JOIN S.s ON r.name = s.name
```

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench, so its MySQL.

Comment: then to access a table from schema s you need toadd s. prefix to the table name.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for MySQL

---

select name from r.r join s.s on r.name = s.name;

---

The general syntax could be:

select attributes from schema_name1.relation_name1 join schema_name2.relation_name2 on common_attribute.relation_name1 = common_attribute.relation_name2;

Comment: It's great to know that your problem is resolved.